# Matlab -- handle objects

Tags: matlab, pass-by-reference, handle

There is a handle class `Foo`:

```
classdef Foo < handle   
    properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public)
        x
    end

    methods
        function obj = foo(x)
            % constructor
            obj.x = x;
        end 
    end       
end
```

I create an object of `Foo`:

```
data = [1 2];
foo = Foo(data);  % handle object
```

I would like to create a reference (*handle*) variable `a` that points to `foo.x`. Is this possible in Matlab? For example, the following does not work:

```
a = foo.x;       % here `a` equals [1 2], `a` is not a handle object  
foo.x = [3 4];   % set property `x` to [3 4];
disp(a);         % a still equals [1 2] 
                 % even though the property `foo.x` has changed
                 % I want `a` to change when `foo.x` is changed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately it is not possible in Matlab. References can be only to objects which are instances of some class inherited from handle (like your class `Foo`). I.e., this is possible:

```
bar = foo
foo.x = [3 4]
disp(bar.x)      % would be [3 4]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's a big limitation of Matlab, unfortunately.