# Simulink - Data Store to a vector in a loop

Tags: matlab, vector, simulink

I would like to store the output of a block (real number - e.g. 2.8), to a vector. The vector has a size 6x1. The 1st output should be recorded at position 1, the 2nd output to position 2 and etc. The 7th, however, should be recorded to position 1, the 8th to position 2 and etc.

Comment: So you only store the most recent 6 values?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: What loop do you mean? Are you using [MATLAB Function Block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)? or is there some combination of blocks making a loop in your simulink model?

Comment: @Wolfie so a circular buffer of size 6...? Sounds like `pos = mod(ind-1,6)+1`.

Comment: @SardarUsama - It's a Matlab Function Block nested within a SubSystem block. I need to take the output from the SubSystem block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular buffer in MATLAB, \*\*without\*\* copying old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890128/circular-buffer-in-matlab-without-copying-old-data)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate if the OP wants to achieve this *in Simulink*? i.e. without writing a MATLAB function block...

Comment: @Wolfie - Thanks for the comment. I would assume that there could be a block that I connect to the input and set my buffer size to 6

Comment: That looks like it: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/buffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to place a [Buffer](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/buffer.html) after the output and set it's size to 6

[image]

Comment: If you want to leave this as an answer, please flesh it out at least with a screenshot of a minimal demo model. This will help future readers.